# How to understand chain multiple => in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am reading below source code in javascript:

```
const switchTo = (menu, select) => (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  select(e.target.value);
  action(() => _.map(menu, ($val, $key) => _.set(menu, $key, false)))();
  action(() => _.set(menu, e.target.value, true))();
};
```

what I don't understand is the first line which includes two `=>` operators. What does this syntax mean? Whether we have a name for that? I don't even know how to search this kind of syntax.

Comment: you could always paste the code into babel - [here](http://babeljs.io/repl/) - to see the ES5 flavour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following syntax describes a function who will accept `a` and `b` and return the sum of the two:

```
const sum = (a, b) => a + b;
```

Which traditionally looks like:

```
function sum(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

In your case, the chained `() =>` represents another function using the `() => { }` syntax being returned:

```
const x = (a, b) => (c) => {
    //              ^^^^^^^^   The returned function.
    //
};
```

Which traditionally looks like:

```
function x(a, b) {
    return function(c) {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`() => {}` is almost same as `function() {}`. Just remember that in arrow functions, there is an implicit return call. Also, when the arrow function call is only a single statement, you won't need the parentheses and they have an implicit return call (thanks @Pineda).

For example, this expression: `() => _.map(menu, ($val, $key) => _.set(menu, $key, false))`

Can be replaced with:

```
function() {
  return _.map(menu, function($val, $key) {
    return _.set(menu, $key, false)
  }
}
```

Also, remember arrow functions are [lexically scoped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047454/what-is-lexical-scope), so `this` has a different meaning.

Comment: **Not all arrow functions have an implicit return call**.  Only if the block body is concise (i.e. a singular expression not surrounded by curly braces with the exception of an object literal) does the arrow function have an implicit return value.  Otherwise you have to _**explicitly**_ include it.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Updated answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's a [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) in that it returns another function. This is actually pretty easy to read once you're used to this notation. When you see multiple `=>`s, read each of them but the last one as `return a function`. Whatever is on the left-hand side of the `=>`, can be *closure'd* so to say in the returned function. The last `=>` is the actual action you want to perform.

`switchTo` from your example, when invoked like this:

```
switchTo(myMenuElement, mySelectElement)
```

produces an event handler that can be attached, for instance, to an element's `onclick` event. When invoked in response the a `click` event, it'll be passed an event arg `e` as usual. The only difference here will be the fact that the handler is now aware of `myMenuElement` and `mySelectElement` and can do something with them too, in addition to `e`.

Answer (score 0):

**=>** is a part of an [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). The first => creates a function that returns second function created with another =>.

Your code transpiled to pure JavaScript with [Babel REPL](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=latest%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=const%20switchTo%20%3D%20(menu%2C%20select)%20%3D%3E%20(e)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20e.preventDefault()%3B%0D%0A%20%20select(e.target.value)%3B%0D%0A%20%20action(()%20%3D%3E%20_.map(menu%2C%20(%24val%2C%20%24key)%20%3D%3E%20_.set(menu%2C%20%24key%2C%20false)))()%3B%0D%0A%20%20action(()%20%3D%3E%20_.set(menu%2C%20e.target.value%2C%20true))()%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B&playground=true):

```
var switchTo = function switchTo(menu, select) {
  return function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    select(e.target.value);
    action(function () {
      return _.map(menu, function ($val, $key) {
        return _.set(menu, $key, false);
      });
    })();
    action(function () {
      return _.set(menu, e.target.value, true);
    })();
  };
};
```