# Why do we use Lexical Scope in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, lexical-scope

I am currently reading Eloquent JS and I understand how Lexical scoping works but I would like to know why do we use it? And what are the practical implications of it?

Comment: `why do we use it?` - because it's how javascript is written - it's like asking "why do we use `return` to return from a function?" because chuzzwuzzah would be a stupid operator name :p

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is lexical scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047454/what-is-lexical-scope)

Comment: Are there any practical implications for this? None of you answered nor did "What is lexical scope?"