# The relationship between Type Symbol and Mirror of Scala reflection

Tags: scala, reflection, types, symbols, mirror

The Scala reflection is really complicated. It contains type symbol and mirror. Could you tell me the relationship between them?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When working with the Scala Reflection API you encounter a lot more types that what you're used to if you've used the Java Reflection API. Given an example scenario where you start with a `String` containing a fully qualified class name of a class, these are the types you are likely to encounter:

- *[Universe](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/environment-universes-mirrors.html#universes)*: Scala supports both runtime and compile time reflection. You choose what kind of reflection you're doing by importing from the corresponding universe. For runtime reflection, this corresponds to the `scala.reflect.runtime` package, for compile time reflection it corresponds to the `scala.reflect.macros` package. This answer focus on the former.

  Like Java you typically start any reflection by choosing which ClassLoader's classes you want to reflect on. Scala provides a shortcut for using the `ClassLoader` of the current class: `scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror`, this gives you a `Mirror` (more on mirrors later). Many JVM applications use just a single class loader, so this is a common entry point for the Scala Reflection API. Since you're importing from `runtime` you're now in that Universe.
- *[Symbols](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html#symbols)*: Symbols contain static metadata about whatever you want to reflect. This includes anything you can think of: is this thing a case class, is it a field, is it a class, what are the type parameters, is it abstract, etc. You may not query anything that might depend on the current lexical scope, for example what members a class has. You may also not interact with the thing you reflect on in any way (like accessing fields or calling methods). You can just query metadata.

  Lexical scope is everything you can "see" at the place you're doing reflection, excluding implicit scope (see [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047454/what-is-lexical-scope) for a treatment of different scopes). How can members of a class vary with lexical scope? Imagine an abstract class with a single `def foo: String`. The name `foo` might be bound to a `def` in one context (giving you a `MethodSymbol` should you query for it) or it could be bound to a `val` in another context (giving you a `TermSymbol`). When working with Symbols it's common to explicitly have to state what kind of symbol you expect, you do this through the methods `.asTerm`, `.asMethod`, `.asClass` etc.

  Continuing the `String` example we started with. You use the `Mirror` to derive a `ClassSymbol` describing the class: `currentMirror.staticClass(myString)`.
- *[Types](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html#types)*: Types lets you query information about the type the symbol refers to in the current lexical context. You typically use `Type`s for two things: querying what vars, vals and defs there are, and querying type relationships (e.g. is this type a subclass of that type). There are two ways of getting hold of a `Type`. Either through a `TypeSymbol` (`ClassSymbol` is a `TypeSymbol`) or through a [`TypeTag`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html).

  Continuing the example you would invoke the `.toType` method on the symbol you got to get the `Type`.
- *[Scopes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/annotations-names-scopes.html#scopes)*: When you ask a `Type` for `.members` or `.decl`—this is what gives you terms (vars and vals) and methods—you get a list of `Symbol`s of the members in the current lexical scope. This list is kept in a type `MemberScope`, it's just a glorified `List[Symbol]`.

  In our example with the abstract class above, this list would contain a `TermSymbol` or a `MethodSymbol` for the name `foo` depending on the current scope.
- *[Names](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/annotations-names-scopes.html#names)*: Names come in two flavors: `TermName` and `TypeName`. It's just a wrapper of a `String`. You can use the type to determine what is named by any `Name`.
- *[Mirrors](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/environment-universes-mirrors.html#mirrors)*: Finally mirrors are what you use to interact with "something". You typically start out with a `Symbol` and then use that symbol to derive symbols for the methods, constructors or fields you want to interact with. When you have the symbols you need, you use `currentMirror` to create mirrors for those symbols. Mirrors lets you call constructors (`ClassMirror`), access fields (`FieldMirror`) or invoke methods (`MethodMirror`). You may not use mirrors to query metadata about the thing being reflected.

So putting an example together reflecting the description above, this is how you would search for fields, invoke constructors and read a `val`, given a `String` with the fully qualified class name:

```
// Do runtime reflection on classes loaded by current ClassLoader
val currentMirror: universe.Mirror = scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror

// Use symbols to navigate to pick out the methods and fields we want to invoke
// Notice explicit symbol casting with the `.as*` methods.
val classSymbol: universe.ClassSymbol = currentMirror.staticClass("com.example.Foo")
val constructorSymbol: universe.MethodSymbol = classSymbol.primaryConstructor.asMethod
val fooSymbol: Option[universe.TermSymbol] = classSymbol.toType.members.find(_.name.toString == "foo").map(_.asTerm)

// Get mirrors for performing constructor and field invocations
val classMirror: universe.ClassMirror = currentMirror.reflectClass(classSymbol)
val fooInstance: Foo = classMirror.reflectConstructor(constructorSymbol).apply().asInstanceOf[Foo]
val instanceMirror: universe.InstanceMirror = currentMirror.reflect(fooInstance)

// Do the actual invocation
val fooValue: String = instanceMirror.reflectField(fooSymbol.get).get.asInstanceOf[String]
println(fooValue) // Prints the value of the val "foo" of the object "fooInstance"
```

Comment: This answer is worthy of a bounty :)