# Pass var between functions on event click

Tags: javascript

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
ApiCall()
console.log(lol)

});



function ApiCall() {
var lol = "this is a test";
}
```

I have looked into the javascript scopes but how would i pass this variable to the first function ?

Comment: use global var? or save your data as one data attribute of one element?

Comment: [`return lol;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) – Related: [What is lexical scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047454/what-is-lexical-scope)

Comment: Where would you put the return lol ? i tried putting it under the Apicall() but it doesn't seem to work thank you for the link will sure read up on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return the value from your function. Like this:

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var passed_lol = ApiCall()
  console.log(passed_lol)
});

function ApiCall() {
  var lol = "this is a test"
  return lol;
}
```

```html
<input id="button" type="button" onclick=stop() value="clickme">
```

Comment: Works like a champ, but if i had to pass 4 variables would the Apicall run for each variable ? because the Apicall is making requests

Comment: I guess that depends on what you mean. Do you need to call the API four times? Or does a single call to the API return four values. Either way, the function can just return an array or object, which can include as many values as you like.

Comment: Also... if it is an API call to a remote service (XHR aka AJAX, etc), it is likely to be asynchronous, so things might need to be a little more complex, requiring the use of things like [`Promise`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and/or [`async`/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function); or the more traditional, callback function.