# React Native setState not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-native, setstate

Can someone explain me why **this.setState** is not a function ?

I do not see why my code has an error

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View , Image} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {res: []}
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('https://api.github.com/repos/torvalds/linux/commits')
            .then(function (response) {
                this.setState({res: response});
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
 }
```

Thank you

Comment: use arrow function to wrap  `this.setState({res: response});` that bring `this` inside arrow function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [`lexical scope`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047454/what-is-lexical-scope) issue. Use [`arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```
.then((response) => {
    this.setState({ res: response });
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the error is `this` does not refer to component class context within resolver function of axios. You can either have resolver function as fat arrow function for your code to work, something like below:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://api.github.com/repos/torvalds/linux/commits')
        .then((response) => {
            this.setState({res: response});
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

or you can change it to something like below:

```
componentDidMount() {
     let self = this;
     axios.get('https://api.github.com/repos/torvalds/linux/commits')
         .then(function(response) {
             self.setState({res: response});
         }).catch(function(error) {
             console.log(error);
         });
 }
```