# React-Native setState not a function

Tags: react-native

I know similar question has been asked before. But this time the example is bit different, so please bear with me.

I am trying to set state inside a react-native component while accessing the keyboard listener -

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidShow',
      this._keyboardDidShow,
    );
    this._keyboardDidShow.bind(this);
    this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidHide',
      this._keyboardDidHide,
    );
    this._keyboardDidHide.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
    this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
  }

  _keyboardDidShow() {
    alert('Keyboard Shown');
    this.setState({keyboardOpen: true});
  }

  _keyboardDidHide() {
    alert('Keyboard Hidden');
    this.setState({keyboardOpen: false});
  }
```

I am getting the error -

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native setState not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51098867/react-native-setstate-not-a-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give those functions access to `this`.

You have 2 ways:

1) Using arrow function

```
_keyboardDidShow = () => {
    alert('Keyboard Shown');
    this.setState({keyboardOpen: true});
  }

  _keyboardDidHide = () => {
    alert('Keyboard Hidden');
    this.setState({keyboardOpen: false});
  }
```

2) Binding them using `bind` in your constructor:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this._keyboardDidShow = this._keyboardDidShow.bind(this)  
    this._keyboardDidHide = this._keyboardDidHide.bind(this)  
}
```

You didn't bind them correctly in your `componentDidMount`

Comment: Another way would be to Use `that = this` and then `that.setState({})`. You can probably think about adding that it in your answer as well

Comment: I've never actually seen your method before. How do the functions get access to `that`? Isn't it the same? @iRohitBhatia

Comment: sorry, I just read setState is not a function and not what `op` was doing in his code. My above method would make the code untidy. In general, you can store the pointer of `this` in a variable (typically people call it `that`) and then use `that` to perform actions like `that.setState` . Although, ideally, even I would use arrow function or bind this.