# Javascript won't fade text and throws no error when run

Tags: javascript, animation

```
window.onload = function() {
  window.setTimeout(fadein, 1000); //2 seconds
}
$( document ).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
$( "#log" ).text( "pageX: " + event.pageX + ", pageY: " + event.pageY );
 var x = event.pageX; 
 if (x > 1200) {
    function fadein() {
      document.getElementById('fadein').style.opacity = '0';

    }
 }
});
```

I just want the text to fade after the mouse x coordinate reaches a certain point. JavaScript throws no error, am I missing any syntax or do I lack a fundamental understanding of how I should go about this process?

Some quick FAQ I might expect:

Yes, I have JQuery loaded

Yes, the HTML/CSS is all consistent in naming.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047454/what-is-lexical-scope

Comment: https://medium.com/@nickbalestra/javascripts-lexical-scope-hoisting-and-closures-without-mystery-c2324681d4be

Comment: Gave you some links to some articles on lexical scoping.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but I nominate `window.setTimeout(fadein, 1000); //2 seconds` as the best comment ever. :)

Comment: @Amadan Let's also not forget that `fadein` function actually hides the element. This guy is hilarious! :)

Answer (score 1):

1. You are defining the `fadein` in your `mousemove` handler. The function is only available in that context so `fadein` in your `onload` handler is `undefined`.
2. `function fadein() { ... }` is a function declaration. You don't call it, so the function body is never executed!

You should define the function *outside* the `mousemove` handler and call it in your `if` statement by using invocation operator: `()`, i.e.: `fadein()`.

```
function fadein() {
  document.getElementById('fadein').style.opacity = '0';
}

window.onload = function() {
  window.setTimeout(fadein, 1000); //2 seconds?
}

$( document ).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
   $( "#log" ).text( "pageX: " + event.pageX + ", pageY: " + event.pageY );
   var x = event.pageX; 
   if (x > 1200) {
     fadein();
   }
});
```

As a side note, setting CSS `opacity` to `0` makes the element invisible. So it actually *fades out* the element.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.

```
function fadein() {
  document.getElementById('fadein').style.opacity = '0';
}
window.onload = function() {
window.setTimeout(fadein, 1000); //2 seconds
}
$( document ).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
$( "#log" ).text( "pageX: " + event.pageX + ", pageY: " +       event.pageY );
var x = event.pageX; 
if (x > 1200) {
 fadein()
}
});
```