# Generic type <T> parameter BEFORE the function name

Tags: java, generics, kotlin

What is the usage of the `<T>` type parameter *before* the function name in Kotlin?

Example:

```
fun <T> MutableList<T>.swap(index1: Int, index2: Int) {
    val tmp = this[index1] 
    this[index1] = this[index2]
    this[index2] = tmp
}
```

Referring to the first `<T>` above.

I've tried to look through the [Kotlin docs](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html) regarding generics as well as the [Java Generics](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) however they mostly just touch on the 2nd `<T>` not the first.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is used to indicate that generics are used and not some type `T` is referenced.

Have a look at this completly valid example

```
fun <String> MutableList<String>.swap(index1: Int, index2: Int)
```

Now this can be called on any `MutableList<*>` and not only `MutableList<String>`. If you would not write `<String>` after the `fun` keyword, how would kotlin know that in fact you were referencing a generic and not `kotlin.String`?

The same goes for the example you've shown. The `<>` after the `fun` just introduces a new generic parameter, else kotlin would complain that it wouldn't know the type `T`

Comment: What's the point of the second `<T>` then if the first `<T>`  allows any MutableList<*>?

Comment: Right. In principle the compiler could be written so it'd handle `fun MutableList<String>.swap<String>` by not trying to resolve the first use of `String` until the opening `(`, but there's no real benefit from doing that and it makes code less readable for a human as well.

Comment: @Zorgan Because this isn't really a good example for generics, you normally need more than one use of `T` in the signature (it may be in the inferred type).

Comment: I'm abit confused why `fun MutableList<Any>.swap(index1: Int, index2: Int)` can't be used to allow for any `MutableList<*>` - as opposed to using "generics" which I'm still wrapping my head around.

Comment: Also the syntax just doesn't make sense to me - how can `String` be the keyword used to allow all types? `fun <String> MutableList<String>.swap(index1: Int, index2: Int)`?

Comment: @Zorgan generics don't have to be named `T` they can be named anything. E.g.`<VeryLongNamesThatHasNumbersLike1234InItAreAlsoAllowed>` is also allowed and would also allow every value. As generics without a bound are implicitly extending `Any?` so `<T>` can be infact written as `<T: Any?>` and can be read as: "Any type `T` that extends `Any` and can be `null`"

Comment: @Zorgan that is why that `<String> MutableList<String>.swap()` is not any different than `MutableList<Any?>.swap()` in your example. But as mentioned in other comments, generic may also be used in different parts and not just the signature, e.g. arguments or return types, like `<T, R> Any?.doSomething(t: T): R`

Comment: Yeah I completely understand Generics in arguments and return types. I just don't get the `<T>` used before `MutableList<String>`. So as I understand it, `fun <AllowAllTypes> MutableList<String>.swap()` would allow any type of `MutableList<>` to be passed through? (not just `<String>`)?

Comment: Also why did you use the possible null-type `MutableList<Any?>.swap()` instead of `MutableList<Any>.swap()`? @Lino

Comment: @Zorgan no, the `<T>` defines that a generic is used, if you **don't define** it then kotlin will not know what `T` is. `fun <AllowAllTypes> MutableList<String>.swap()` will only work for `MutableList<String>` because you don't use the generic `AllowAllTypes` you've defined, *anywhere*.

Comment: @Zorgan I would recommend that you read more about generics, a decent tutorial can probably explain it better than I am currently.

Comment: "that is why that `<String> MutableList<String>.swap()` is not any different than `MutableList<Any?>.swap()` in your example" It _is_ different: you can pass e.g. a `MutableList<Int>` to the first one but not to the second. To understand this you need to read about variance in docs, but I strongly suggest delaying it until you understand the basics.

Comment: The only part I'm not getting is the Left hand side generic type. I will look further into it - but are you able to give a practical example of a generic type function like the one I posted: `fun <T> MutableList<T>.funcName()...` ?

Comment: @Zorgan I don't really understand what you don't understand... If you create an object of type `String` or `Int` then you reference the `class String/Int`. If you don't really care what the actual class is though, then you can use generics. So you could say that you "create" an placeholder `T` (it is not created as an actual type) when writing `fun <T>` and you then reference said placeholder whenever you do something like `MutableList<T>.swap()` when calling the method `swap()` with a `MutableList<String>` you can think about it like this that every occurance of `T` is replaced with `String`.

Comment: That's the bit I understand perfectly. What I don't understand is the first `<T>` (for example the first `<T>` in this: `fun <T> MutableList<T>.funcName()...`)

Comment: @Zorgan oh, that is just syntax, I guess to probably make it easier for the compiler to distinguish between real classes and generic parameters.

Comment: Thanks. Can you just confirm - the first `<T>` will always be the same as the 2nd `<T>`?

Comment: @Zorgan it is by definition so, though I can't find the specs confirming this

Comment: Thanks - one last question. Is there a performance upgrade when doing `fun <T> sort(para: T){}` over `fun sort(para: Any){}`?

Comment: @Zorgan as generics are only used at compile time you will not find any performance issues. I suggest reading about *type erasure* to learn more about this

Answer (score 6):

(Here's another approach.)

Consider a normal, non-generic function:

```
fun myFun(a: Int, b: String) {
    // …use a and b…
}
```

What are `a` and `b`?  They don't mean anything yet.  They're simply saying ‘When you call this function, you must pass these values’.  You'd expect the body of the function to refer to them in some way; that's when they get used.

Now consider a generic function:

```
fun <T, U> myFun(/* …use T and U… */) {
    // …
}
```

It's the same with `T` and `U`.  Those are parameters, too — *type* parameters.  Just like with value parameters, declaring type parameters doesn't mean anything by itself, but gives placeholders for types that must be passed (explicitly or inferred) when calling the function.  (The `<…>` declaration also gives a place to specify any constraints or variance, e.g. `<T : Number>` or `<out T>`.)  And you'd normally use those type parameters later on — in this case, in the rest of the function signature.

Comment: Thanks. I understand they're type parameters, what I don't understand is when there are 2 blocks of type parameters like this: `fun <T> MutableList<T>.swap()` - why does the first `<T>` need to be there?

Comment: The first `<T>` is saying “This is the type parameter you have to pass”, and the second is saying “the MutableList must be of type T”.  The first is _declaring_ the type parameter, the second is _using_ it — just like value parameters must be declared in the function declaration, before they're used in the body.

Comment: Thanks. So the first `<T>` should be the same type as the 2nd `<T>` (first T is declaration, 2nd T is the actual instance). However, doesn't this make the first `<T>`) redundant? It's like in Java when declaring a variable: `Class test = new Class()` - Kotlin removed the requirement for the first `Class` (variable type) because it's redundant.

Comment: It's not redundant, for two reasons.  First, it's a place to specify constraints, variance, &c (e.g. `<T : Number>`, `<out T>`).  And second, it provides a namespace, identifying `T` as a type parameter and not the name of a class or interface.  (Type parameters are usually a single upper-case letter, partly to avoid clashes; but there's nothing stopping you from declaring a `class T`, or declaring `<String>` as a type parameter.  Without the declaration, the compiler would have no way to be sure what you meant.)

Comment: @Zorgan Translate to non-generic functions as suggested by this answer: does using `a` inside the body of `myFun` make the `a: Int` parameter redundant because it should be the same value?

Answer (score 3):

To add to Lino's answer, imagine this definition has invisible braces after type parameter declaration:

```
fun <T> \*{*\ MutableList<T>.swap(index1: Int, index2: Int) {...} \*}*\
```

So it's properly [lexically scoped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047454/what-is-lexical-scope). If that `<T>` went after function name, you'd lose this property, complicate the parser, and only make code less readable for humans.

It would also be hard to remember to put `<T>` before name for extension functions, but after it for member functions. Bad enough that it has to be done for classes!

Scala does put `[T]` after the method name, but that's because it has a very different syntax for the feature corresponding to extension methods. Scala 3 will [go for the complicated parser approach](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/extension-methods.html#generic-extensions), probably because Kotlin-like syntax would not fit with any other syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The first `<T>` introduces a *generic type parameter* to the function, as you know. The second `<T>` it's part of `MutableList<T>`, the *receiver* of the [*extension function*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) that your code is defining: an extension function is defined as

fun [GenericTypeList] ReceiverType.FunctionName([ParametersList]) [: ReturnType] { ... }

as you can see in the official documentation I linked above. The *receiver type* is the type you add the *extension function* to (*extension functions* are *syntactic sugar* for something like (Java's) `static` method invocations). In you example you're adding an extension function to *generic* `MutableList<T>`, so defining the *receiver* you provides a generic type specification (which requires the *generic type parameter* represented by the first `<T>`).

I hope my explanation can bel clear and exaustive for you!

Comment: The syntax just doesn't make sense to me. What is the point of generic type if `fun MutableList<Any>.swap(index1: Int, index2: Int)` already allows for any `MutableList<*>`?

Answer (score 0):

"T" representing generic type/class you passing to the function. Your question is about the "T" at returning of the function. So it suppose return the type/class based on what you passing in to function.