# Generic function in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin you can have a generic function like this:

```
fun <T> singletonList(item: T): List<T> {
    // ...
}
```

I don't understand what the purpose of the `<T>` after the fun keyword is for. The function returns `List<T>`, so what is the point of `<T>`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generic type <T> parameter BEFORE the function name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54880432/generic-type-t-parameter-before-the-function-name)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be able to create a generic function the compiler must know that you want to work with diferent types. Kotlin is (like Java or C#) a strongly typed language. so just passing different types into a function will make the compiler mad.

To tell the compiler that a function should be accepting multiple types you need to add a "Type Parameter"

The `<T>` after `fun` is the definition of said "Type Parameter".
Which is then used at the `item` Argument.

Now the compiler knows that you'll specifiy the type of `item` when you make the call to `singletonList(item: T)`

Just doing

```
fun singletonList(item: T) : List<T> {[...]}
```

would make the compiler unhappy as it does not know `T`.
(As long as you don't have a class named `T`)

You also can have multiple "Type Params" when you separate them with commas:

```
fun <T, U> otherFunction(firstParam: T, secondParam: U): ReturnType
```

Comment: Still isn't clear. The function already has a type parameter (item: T).

Comment: no if you only would write `func funcName(item: T)` the compiler would be mad at you because it does not know `T`... Thats why you need the `<T>` in front. That is what tells the compiler that T is a TypeParam. `(item: T)` is the usage and `<T>` is the definition

Comment: OK. So how would do define a function that has 3 parameters and the first and last one are types T and U?

Comment: `fun <T, U> funcName(firstParam: T, second: AnotherType, third: U): ReturnType`

Answer (score 1):

This is a generic function which, as per the language's syntax requirements, needs to provide this part `<T>`. You can use it to specify `T` further:

```
fun <T: Number> singletonList(item: T): List<T> {
    // ...
}
```

It's also common to have multiple generic types:

```
fun <T: Number, R: Any> singletonList(item: T): R {
    // ...
}
```