# Arrow functions without block bodies do not create lexical scope, right?

Tags: javascript

I just would like to get the confirmation of the thesis in the subject.
It's not possible to somehow create local scope, i.e. local variables inside a function like `x => some_expression`, in contrary to a function like `x => {/*any code*/}`, is it?

Subquestion: does lexical scope can only be created between curly braces? e.g. in blocks, conditions, loops, try/catch etc.

P.S. I am 99% sure of that, but I want to know maybe I missed something...

Comment: "Does lexical scope can only be created between curly braces?" One exception to the rule is single line blocks where braces are optional. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047454/what-is-lexical-scope

Comment: can you examplify @AvinKavish

Comment: @AvinKavish Agreed with Shubh, can you please give an example, I am not quite understand the case you are writing about.

Comment: I am bit confused here with the local scope and lexical scope ,are you relating them ?@NurbolAlpysbayev. What you are terming is block scope  ,not lexical scope,I guess

Comment: @Shubh Aren't they the same? Local scope is a lexical scope, but the opposite is not true.

Comment: The arrow function mechanic has no difference in terms of scope. It just does not create this, args, etc. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating local scope via new variables is not possible for a "concise body" arrow function because there is no way to define a new variable inside of an expression.

If you were to write `const func = x => const a` or `const func = x => const a = x` it would fail.

Comment: Even if variables cannot be declared, the scope is still lexical and closing on outer variables.

Comment: Indeed. So "concise body" arrow functions can only have expressions in their bodies, and a variable declaration is not an expression, it is a statement.

Comment: @AvinKavish that makes sense, so inside a concise body function, you can still refer to variables in outer functions