# Can't access global variable in while loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop

I am trying to solve this programming problem, but i am unable to access the global variable inside the while loop. It gives me undefined when i access the global variable.

```js
function equal(h1, h2, h3) {
  let sum1 = 0;
  let sum2 = 0;
  let sum3 = 0;
  let first = [];
  let second = [];
  let third = [];
  let count = 0;
  while (h1.length !== 0) {
    var popped = h1.pop();
    sum1 += popped;
    first.push(popped);
  }
  while (h2.length !== 0) {
    var popped = h2.pop();
    sum2 += popped;
    second.push(popped);
  }
  while (h3.length !== 0) {
    var popped = h3.pop();
    sum3 += popped;
    third.push(popped);
  }
  while (sum1 === sum2 && sum2 === sum3 && sum3 === sum1) {
    // Below two consoles are not printing anything.
    console.log(sum1, sum2, sum3);
    console.log(h1, h2, h3);
    if (sum1 > sum2) {
      var x = first.pop();
      sum1 = sum1 - x;
    } else if (sum2 > sum3) {
      var y = second.pop();
      sum2 = sum2 - y;
    } else {
      var z = third.pop();
      sum3 = sum3 - z;
    }
  }
}

console.log(equal([3, 2, 1, 1, 1], [4, 3, 2], [1, 1, 4, 1]));
```

Comment: Your function does not return anything so `console.log` will print "undefined".

Comment: I meant, when i access console.log(sum1, sum2, sum3) or console.log(h1, h2, h3) indside it prints undefined.

Comment: @devesh None of those are global variables, they're all local to the function.

Comment: You may not understand what global variables are. Here's a good [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786851/define-global-variable-in-a-javascript-function) to help you.

Comment: But, i can access variables inside the function anywhere. right?

Comment: Please update the code you posted to show the actual problem you're having. Add the `console.log` calls that aren't working as expected.

Comment: you're never getting to those `console.log` lines because the `while` condition is not true.

Comment: `sum1 == 8, sum2 == 9, sum3 == 7`, so you never go into the `while` loop at all.

Comment: @devesh Please don't forget to accept an answer by checking the checkmark next to each answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning anything from your method `equal()`. So if you try to console it, it will display `undefined`. Please try returning some value.

---

**Code Snippet Attached (Edited)**

```js
function equal(h1, h2, h3){
    let sum3 = 0;
    let third = [];
    let count = 0;
    while (h3.length !== 0){
        var popped = h3.pop();
        sum3 += popped;
        third.push(popped);
        //here are the global variables inside while loop
        console.log(sum3)
    }
}

console.log(equal([ 3, 2, 1, 1, 1 ], [ 4, 3, 2 ], [ 1, 1, 4, 1 ]));
```

Comment: This is true, but what does it have to do with accessing global variables in the `while` loop?

Comment: His comment says **when i access console.log(sum1, sum2, sum3) or console.log(h1, h2, h3) indside it prints undefined**

Comment: @Barmar we can access global variable inside while loop, I have updated my answer, in the code snippet, you can see the global variable being printed.

Answer (score 1):

### Some Definitions

[Global Variables and Scope](https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/)

[Lexical Scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047454/what-is-lexical-scope)

---

### Some Misunderstandings

**1. Misunderstanding what a global variable is.**

Variables are accessible within a function's [lexical scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047454/what-is-lexical-scope) and evaluated in order, from local scope, to parent scope, to global scope (`window` in a browser, `global` in nodejs). What you're referring to as "global scope" is actually the local scope of the `equal` function or a `while` loop.

**2. Expecting a value to be returned from `equal` without a return statement**

```
console.log(equal([3, 2, 1, 1, 1], [4, 3, 2], [1, 1, 4, 1]));
```

`equal` doesn't return anything, so nothing will be logged to the console.

**3. Misunderstanding how JavaScript is evaluated**

JavaScript evaluates code synchronously (read [this](https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-does-javascript-actually-work-part-1-b0bacc073cf) for more information). So, your `while` loops are evaluated in sequence, one a time, until the length of each array they're evaluating becomes 0. Then your final `while` loop will be evaluated.

```
while(sum1 === sum2 && sum2 === sum3 && sum3 === sum1)
```

This loop will only ever iterate if all 3 conditions are true. Invoking `equal` as you did:

```
equal([3, 2, 1, 1, 1], [4, 3, 2], [1, 1, 4, 1])
```

will result in the final `while` loop being false (this is pseudo code):

```
sum1 = (3 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1) = 8 
sum2 = (4 + 3 + 2) = 9 
sum3 = (1 + 1 + 4 + 1) = 7
---
sum1 != sum2 && sum2 != sum3 && sum3 != sum1
```

So the iteration won't occur and `console.log(sum1, sum2, sum3)`, inside of your final `while` loop will not be printed.