# Can someone explain why `this` is referring different context in these two methods in JS?

Tags: javascript, this

I have two ways to define `sayHi` method:

```
1. BoardMember.prototype.sayHi = ()=>{return `Hi, my name is ${this.name}. I am from ${this.homeState}, and I was trained in ${this.training}.`}

2. BoardMember.prototype.sayHi = function(){
  return `Hi, my name is ${this.name}. I am from ${this.homeState}, and I was trained in ${this.training}.`
}
```

When I try to call `someBoardMember.sayHi()`, the first one's `this` refers to the global object, `window`, while the second one refers to the `someBoardMember`, I don't really get why. Don't they have the same receiver? What makes `this` different??

Comment: It's due to you using an arrow function (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: It is because In Es6 arrow functions use lexical "this", You are technically targeting the window object when you use an arrow function as a method within an object.  Here is some more info about it.  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047454/what-is-lexical-scope)