# Javascript rest param in nested functions

Tags: javascript

I came across this piece of code ... where `args` is interpreted to `fn` `args object` ... this is really confusing for me, and I couldn't get it

```
function memoize(fn) {
    return function(...args) {
        fn.apply(this, args);
    }
}
```

How does the inner function understand that `args` passed to it belongs to `fn`

**Edit**

Now I get it ...
This wrapper function should be called this way `const fastfunction = memoize(slowfunction);` ... and the returned function (the inner-function) 'd be `fastFunction` which should be called with a set of args... and `...args` is kinda a placeholder for these args

Comment: It doesn’t. It only applies the arguments given to it to fn

Comment: The inner function itself applies the variable `fn` to itself as an argument. The "applied to" is given as `this`, and the application is on `args`.

Comment: This is the classical `memoize` wrapper that should be used this way ---> `const fastfunction = memoize(slowfunction);` ... and it successfully cal `fn` with its arguments ... and I have no idea how does that happen ?

Comment: Thank you so much guys ... appreciate ut ... this was really confusing ...

Comment: After `const fastfunction = memoize(slowfunction)`, the returned `fastfunction` (inner function) remembers what `fn` is because of how [lexical scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047454/what-is-lexical-scope) works. When you then call `fastfunction`, the arguments are applied to `fn` (`slowfunction`) due to `fn.apply(this, args)`. Say the argumets are `1`, `2` and `3`. Then `fastfunction(1,2,3)` is passing those arguments to `fn` (which is set to `slowfunction`). So it is the same as `slowfunction(1,2,3)`

Answer (score 0):

the this in this example has no effect since it is undefined it is not binded to any function or object
this :

```
function memoize(fn) {
  return function(...args) {
     //in this example you can replace this by null since it is undefined 
      fn.apply(this, args);
  }
}
```

is similar to this :

```
function memoize(fn) {
  return function (args) {
      fn(args);
  }
}
```

Nested functions have access to the variables declared in the outer function, just like functions have access to the variables declared outside of the functions. you can check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

in your example you are using the concept of closure and closure gives you access to an outer function’s scope from an inner function. In JavaScript, closures are created every time a function is created, at function creation time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ... but `return function(...args)` is way different than `return function function(args)` .. the first represent a function with **unknown num of arguments** ... the second is a signature for a function that shoudl have **only one arg**

Comment: Function (...args) in this cas i agree with u this represent function with unknown aargs in the case of declaration of the function but with you call a function and you pass it ...args that means you call a function with list of the args array , it's not the same

Comment: I Hope this help