# Why does it print 1 instead of 100 in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am learning about javascript closure, I have this program

```js
var x = 1;

function f1(){
  console.log(x);
}

f1()

function f2(){
  var x = 100;
  f1();
}

f2()
```

It prints

```
1
1
```

But according to my understanding it should print

```
1
100
```

Since, the second time `f1()` is being executed inside `f2()`'s execution context where x is 100, also needless to say `var` is function scoped. So why is it printing `1` istead of `100`?

Comment: An inadvertent lesson in why global variables are bad.

Comment: Because f1 prints the value from the closure where f1 is created (not invoked). More about closures: https://javascript.info/closure

Comment: You must notice to `global variable` vs `local variable`. The first `x` is global and the second one is local and your function show the global `x` but you change the local variable.

Comment: What you are asking about is the difference between [Lexical and Dynamic scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047454/what-is-lexical-scope)

Comment: @Drdilyor maybe you want to write an answer around that link because I think you are much more on point with that than I was in my answer (I didn't know about dynamic scoping existing in other languages)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`f1` doesn't have its own `x`, so it refers to the global `x`, which is 1 and you never change it. `f2` *does* have a local `x` in scope which it refers to, which is 100, but there is no code in `f2` that ever refers to it! The only `console.log` you have is in `f1`, referring to the global `x`, and you are calling it twice (once from the top-level code and once from inside `f2`, but where it's called from doesn't matter)

You are saying the second time `f1` is called from `f2`'s execution context but that doesn't matter, when you call a function a new execution context is created and `f2`' s won't have `f1`'s variables in scope (in its lexical environment to use the correct term here) unless you would nest the whole definition of `f1` into `f2`. The scopes are fixed* at compile time, they won't change at runtime based on the call stack.

*: In terms of their variables' location in the source code. Since every invocation of a function creates a new scope where those local variables can have new values, technically it *is* of course set at runtime, but it would still be the same `var`/`let`/etc in the source code that is referred to every time.

See also: https://javascript.info/closure (this has a great explanation, as already mentioned by Andrejs Kuzmins in the comments)

Comment: " unless you would nest the whole definition of f1 into f2. " that makes sense. So you are saying f1() in f2() here is not a closure?

Comment: Exactly. Note that when you _would_ nest the definitions, then `f1` would instead no longer be callable from the top-level code since it wouldn't be in scope there, and also you would technically get a new, different `f1` every time `f2` is invoked because it would refer to a different execution context in a parent scope every time (you could return the nested function from the outer function and reference it later and it would still use the same `x` it had originally even if you had invoked `f2` several more times since then, let's say with a `x = Math.random()` in it)

Answer (score 4):

In Javascript a function can access variables from the scopes when it is *defined*, not called. In other words, It doesn't matter where the function is called, but where is defined - does matter.

I would suggest reading [this](https://javascript.info/closure) article/book, but [Russian one](https://learn.javascript.ru/closure) is more comprehensive

---

This is called *Lexical Scoping*, There are some languages that would do the opposite: it doesn't matter where the function is defined, all scopes function can access depends where the function is called. This is called *Dynamic Scoping*

Comment: Thanks, it was so much helpful, it is all about lexical environment

Answer (score 0):

Cancel var in f2 function

```js
var x = 1;

function f1(){
  console.log(x);
}

f1()

function f2(){
  x = 100;
  f1();
}

f2()
```

Comment: Okay thank you, but can you describe in terms of execution context, why the first approach is giving 1,1?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question why `f2`'s `x` isn't in scope inside of `f1` when invoked from inside `f2`

Comment: Okay i did not give description but what is the reason of giving downvote since I gave working solution? @CherryDT

Comment: The reason was that the OP didn't ask for a way for it to print 1 and 100 but instead they asked why it printed 1 and 1 and what is wrong in their understanding of closures. You didn't answer the question but instead provided a solution for a non-problem that wasn't asked.

Answer (score -4):

Using var in statement var x =100 initializes another variable that is not in scope for f1 so remove the var
Just x =100 will give the desired result.

Comment: hey thanks for the response, it's not about the desired result, I want to understand why is it the way it is.