# How can I replace an image based on result of ajax request?

Tags: ajax

I'm making a  bingo style game. I generate cards with images in each cell. When a cell is clicked I want to change the cell image based on the response to an ajax call. I have tried many variations of the following code without success:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    $('img').click(function (event) {
        var src = $(this).attr("src");
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var ref = src +' ' + id;
        if(src == 'cards/cardon.gif') return false;

        $.ajax({ 
            url: "checkBingo.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:{"ref":ref},
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
                if(response.indexOf('Strike') != -1) $(this).attr('src', 'images/cross.png'); 
                else if (src != 'images/bingo.jpeg') $(this).attr('src', 'cards/cardon.gif');
            }       
        })  
        return false;
   })            
});
```

I know the response contains 'Strike' but neither of the images is being set.   Please help

I've tried many variations including setting a var based on response.indexOf('Strike') != -1) and then swapping the images outside the ajax call

Answer (score 0):

In your `success` callback, the context (i.e. the value of `this`) has changed, and does not refer to the image element you would like to update anymore.

To work around this, there are two options:

### Cache the image reference

In the outer scope, cache the image reference and reuse it in your callback:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img').click(function (event) {
        var $img = $(this);
        var src = $img.attr("src");
        var id = $img.attr("id");
        var ref = src +' ' + id;
        if (src == 'cards/cardon.gif') return false;

        $.ajax({ 
            url: "checkBingo.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:{"ref":ref},
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
                if(response.indexOf('Strike') != -1) $img.attr('src', 'images/cross.png'); 
                else if (src != 'images/bingo.jpeg') $img.attr('src', 'cards/cardon.gif');
            }       
        })  
        return false;
   })            
});
```

### Use an arrow function with lexical scoping

If your environment allows you to use arrow functions (which have [lexical scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047454/what-is-lexical-scope), preventing the value of `this` to change), you can use an arrow function to define your callback:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img').click(function (event) {
        var src = $(this).attr("src");
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var ref = src +' ' + id;
        if (src == 'cards/cardon.gif') return false;

        $.ajax({ 
            url: "checkBingo.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:{"ref":ref},
            success: (response) => {
                alert(response);
                if(response.indexOf('Strike') != -1) $(this).attr('src', 'images/cross.png'); 
                else if (src != 'images/bingo.jpeg') $(this).attr('src', 'cards/cardon.gif');
            }       
        })  
        return false;
   })            
});
```

Comment: Wow, so fast. Thank you. Your first option worked perfectly