# Dynamic Variable Closure in Common Lisp (SBCL)

Tags: scope, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I understand how this code works:

```
(defvar *nums* '(2 3 5))

(defun print-nums ()
  (format t "~a~%" *nums*))

(print-nums)
-> (2 3 5)
-> NIL
```

I even understand how the new value of the dynamically bound variable `*nums*` is passed on to `print-nums` in this code:

```
(let ((*nums* '(1 2 3)))
  (print-nums))
-> (1 2 3)
-> NIL
```

But why doesn't the code below work the same way?

```
(defvar *my-nums-f* (let ((*nums* '(1 2 3)))
                      #'(lambda () (format t "~a~%" *nums*))))

(funcall *my-nums-f*)
-> (2 3 5)
-> NIL
```

Does the concept of a closure not apply to dynamically bound variables, or am I doing something wrong? If I have wrongly understood the concept of a closure, could someone please explain it to me?

Comment: You can look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463463/dynamic-and-lexical-variables-in-common-lisp) (Dynamic and Lexical variables in Common Lisp) and the relative answers, in particular to [the answer of Rainer Joswig](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2386051/2382734).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(defvar *my-nums-f* (let ((*nums* '(1 2 3)))
                      #'(lambda () (format t "~a~%" *nums*))))
```

Here we set `*my-nums-f*` to the result of

```
(let ((*nums* '(1 2 3)))
  #'(lambda () (format t "~a~%" *nums*)))
```

This form starts by dynamically binding `*nums*` to `'(1 2 3)`, then returning `#'(lambda () (format t "~a~%" *nums*))`, which is a function. At the end, we reset `*nums*` back to `'(2 3 5)`.

```
(funcall *my-nums-f*)
```

Here we call the function stored in `*my-nums-f*`, which is `(lambda () (format t "~a~%" *nums*))`. This function takes the current value of `*nums*`, which is `'(2 3 5)`.

```
-> (2 3 5)
-> NIL
```

You seem to expect that the `lambda` somehow inlines the current values of all variables used in the function body, which would indeed result in `(format t "~a~%" '(1 2 3))` at that point.

But that's not how it works: The function refers to the variable itself, not a shapshot of the variable's value. That's why the function sees whatever the current value of `*nums*` is at the time it is called.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another look simulating dynamic vars. Assume NUMS is a dynamic var bound to '(2 3 5) before calling BAR. NUMS is free within the lambda and is closed over. But, before the lambda returns, NUMS is rebound. This is what happens when a dynamic var falls out of the lexical scope that pushed a new binding onto its little stack of values.

```
(defun bar ()
  (let ((nums '(1 2 3)))
    (prog1
        (lambda () nums)
      (setf nums '(2 3 5)))))
```

SBCL will tell you if it has created a closure or not: `#<FUNCTION ...>` vs `#<CLOSURE ...>`. Your code does not create a closure because there are no free vars in the body of the lambda.